# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable pyscreeze

Tags: python

I tried to detect a picture in the present screen. Sometimes it can found the picture and return the result position of picture. But sometimes it can found while it exist in present screen. In that time, it got error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Because no result found. I tried to throw when cannot found the result by

```
try:
    a,b,c,d = pyscreeze.locateOnScreen('pic.png')
except AttributeError:
    print('no object found on screen')
```

to pass it and continue find again but sadly, it not work. So, have anyway to throw the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` when no picture found?

Comment: `except TypeError` not `AttributeError`

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks for anwser :). btw this lib quite bad :(, the rate to find a image is under 10%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `except` the type of error that is raised, so in this case it should be:

```
try:
    a,b,c,d = pyscreeze.locateOnScreen('pic.png')
except TypeError:
#      ^
    print('no object found on screen')
```

Note it is possible to `except` without specifying the error type, but this is not good practice generally.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyScreeze/0.1.0, `locateOnScreen()` returns `None` if it doesn't find anything, so you probably want your code to be something like this:

```
position = pyscreeze.locateOnScreen('pic.png')
if position is None:
    print("Not found")
else:
    a,b,c,d = position
```

Comment: can you suggest to me a library better than pyscreeze to find image in present screen?